# How to deal with an uncaught exception error in Meteor?

Tags: javascript, node.js, meteor, error-handling, uncaught-exception

How do I listen to an uncaught exception error in meteor?

The errors are of course specific to the cause, so please can you provide a pseudo style code/explanation that states the concept of handling this error.

An example use case:

A user clicks 'logout' but there is an uncaught exception and the user does not get logged out and so the connection to the server remains open.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the callbacks, they usually provide a `reason` parameter. E.g

```
Meteor.call("some_random_non_existent_method", function(err, result) {
    if(err) return alert(err.reason)
});
```

Most meteor callbacks have a `error` param. With the logout its `Meteor.logout(function(err) { ... })`

You should be able to catch most types of errors like this. If you want to capture all errors you can use try..catch. Everything in the `try` block will try to run until it throws an error. You can `catch` this and provide feedback to the user.

```
try {
    //This will throw an error
    this.run_something.go_make_error()
}catch(e) {
    alert("There was an error running this");
}
```

Comment: So if catch (or more specifically,  match an uncaught exception condition in the Meteor.logout error callback object, how would I log the user out? 
Do I use "process.exit()" after the alert message within the function? And then maybe alert the user to try logging out again?

Comment: @CodeCandy keep in mind `process.exit()` only works on the server side. It would exit the app entirely. If there is an error when the user logs out the best thing to do is let them know what the issue is and let them try again. Its not likely to help by trying to log out again. For example, one scenario it would not log out is if the internet was cut out but there's no way to help in this scenario besides alerting the user that they can reconnect first to log out.

Comment: Thank you, this solution makes perfect sense.